# How do I get the table to display the duplicated as the title and the time as the results?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am planning to make a schedule for the bus however, I've encounter some problems that I do not know how to resolve.

Desired output

[image]

What I got:

[image]

View:

```
foreach($wkdayBus as $row){
    $time = $row->busTime;
    $busstop = $row->busStop;

    echo "<tr><th>".$busstop."</th>";

    echo "<td>".$time."</td></tr>";
}
```

Model

```
function getWeekdayBusSchedule() {
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT busStop,busTime from busschedule inner join bustime on busschedule.busScheduleID=bustime.busScheduleID WHERE dayType = 'Weekday';");

    $results = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $result) {
        $results[] = $result;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the time in the false dimension. Your table should look like this:

```
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 1</th>
   <th>Bust Stop 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Bus Stop 1 time 1</td>
   <td>Bus Stop 2 time 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Bus Stop 1 time 2</td>
   <td>Bus Stop 2 time 2</td>
</tr>
...
```

Currently it look something like this:

```
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 1</th>
   <td>Bust Stop 1 time 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 1</th>
   <td>Bust Stop 1 time 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 1</th>
   <td>Bust Stop 1 time 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 2</th>
   <td>Bust Stop 2 time 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 2</th>
   <td>Bust Stop 2 time 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Bust Stop 2</th>
   <td>Bust Stop 2 time 3</td>
</tr>
```

Also I recommend you to use the [PHP date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to format your time properly.

Comment: I've been thinking of how to do that do u have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @JoshSoh Yes, just reorganise the result and echo the Busstations first. Then iterate through all times an add echo them.

Comment: can you show me how it is done? I've been reorganizing but still I can't get my desire result